# How do I clear the [Ignore] cache for test methods? (without restarting Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

I have some tests that were marked as `[Ignore]`, but now, I want to run them again, so I remove the `[Ignore]` attribute, but Visual Studio still treats them as ignored.

What can I do to clear the cache to not ignore the tests anymore?

**Update:**

It looks like this data is stored in the vsmdi file:

```
<TestLink ... name="MethodName" ... enabled="false" />
```

So deleting the vsdmi file, or otherwise causing it to be regenerated is necessary.

But, visual studio caches it, so restarting visual studio seems to fix the problem (sometimes at least).

Comment: I can rename the method, but I don't want to rename the method. Even renaming it back remembers the old ignore state.

Comment: I have also discovered that I can rename the class.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Clean Solution (in the build menu)? Also I would try deleting the bin/obj folders from the test-project. If that doesn't work I'd look for other (binary) files that might be a cache of some sort or related to test-projects and just delete them. I can't imagine it to be hard to locate such files and just delete them (make sure you have a backup, just in case).

**EDIT** [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530442/215042) it's the .vsmdi file.
**EDIT2** [Apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442252/how-do-i-clear-the-ignore-cache-for-test-methods/11530436#comment15243303_11530436) :P

If I would've encountered such a problem I might even have done a filesearch looking for specific method-names that have been [ignored]. Make sure you use a tool that looks "inside" every file, windows file-search ignores a crapton of files.

Comment: I'd search the entire project directory (using \*.\* to make sure nothing is missed). I use my own homebrew tool for this kind of purpose but you might find a good tool [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11530442/215042). Whatever you do, **avoid** "SpectateSwamp Desktop Search" :P

Comment: As you guessed, Clean didn't clean it up.

Comment: And it's not the VSMDI file either.

Comment: I know it's a caveman approach but, when unsure, just start trashing files that you believe might be the cause (and let us know which one it is). As long as you have a decent backup (or VCS in place) it shouldn't be a problem. All I'm trying to convey here is that it can't be that hard to find the cause; after having pinpointed the cause you can better direct your Google-queries towards a better and/or more permanent solution (and maybe even find a hotfix/patch). It's a shame I can't reproduce your problem on my system, otherwise I would've been able to better assist you in your quest.

Answer (score 2):

We have this issue where I work as well.

You can manually change the .vsmdi file or delete it. If you open the test view again (after deleting it) it will generate a new file.

Also, the same kind of issue can occured with which test settings you have selected. It will 'cache' that as well.

Comment: Decent solution, but I see two problems: 1) Messing with the vsmdi file still seems like a workaround, and it's not as simple as renaming the class or method, which works well enough. 2) our VSMDI file is generated based on other test method attributes, so that makes the process more difficult.

Comment: My apologies, I could have sworn that's how we fixed it. I know when I change the test settings, I close the solution, close visual studio, and reopen both to make sure the test settings actually changed. You could try that. But now I feel like I'm guessing. :P

Comment: Oh, I have to close visual studio too? That's annoying. That means there's 3 strikes against it. I'll give that a shot though.

Comment: MSTest in Visual Studio has some issues. I think you are better off renaming the test. But if you ever use multiple test settings (like we do - one for Code Coverage and one for normal test runs) then you'll need to do this anyway.

Comment: Yeah, we have a tool that generates tests lists (into the vsmdi file) from attributes, so that's what I've been doing, renaming the tests, I just want a better solution than "restart visual studio"

Answer (score 1):

Even while this topic is quite old, I'd like to add my solution to this problem, for anyone who's having the same problem...

I recenlty had this problem also, and found the solution in the .vsmdi file.
Under '**Test Settings**', '**Unit Test**' a had a folder referred in '*Root folder for the assemblies to be loaded:*' and the checkbox '*Use the Load Context for assemblies in the test directory*' was checked.

I unchecked the checkbox, and after that, my tests did run succesfully! (I knew the files referred in 'Root folder....' where old assemblies.
You can also remove the files from folder in 'Root folder...' to make sure your old assemblies are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Visual Studio 2012 and did not have a .vsdmi file but ran into the issue.  I was able to solve this by deleting the .suo (hidden file next the .sln file) file and restarting the Visual Studio.  I know it says without restarting but the provided solution didn't work for me so I am providing an alternative in case someone else runs into the same error.