# Clear MSTest cache

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Using Visual Studio 2019 v16.11.16 with MSTest v3.0.2.

Having an odd problem. Breakpoints are being hit in the method marked with `TestMethod`. But breakpoints are NOT hit in the generator method marked with the `DynamicData` attribute.

```
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(SomeGeneratorMethod), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void MainTestMethod(string input, string expectedExpanded)
{
    // Breakpoints are hit in here...
}

// ...

private static IEnumerable<object[]> SomeGeneratorMethod()
{
    // But breakpoints are not being hit in here...
}
```

Now deliberately introduce an error in the generator method which throws an exception. For example, add the same key twice to a Dictionary. Now breakpoints **get hit**, although an exception gets thrown which stops the tests. Stop debugging, remove the deliberate error...and breakpoints are not hit again!

Moreover, existing test cases that were defined in the generator method earlier today can be changed and when tests are run the new test case value is used. But new test cases added in the generator do NOT generate a new test case in `Test Explorer` and are not run at all.

This must surely be a caching bug in Visual Studio. This [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442252) has suggestions for earlier version of Visual Studio. For example, deleting a `vsmdi` file is suggested, but I cannot find any such file on my system.

Where does Visual Studio cache MSTest-based values and how do I force Visual Studio to clear whatever internal database/cache it is hanging onto?

#### UPDATE

Things I have tried so far:

- Right-click solution and select `Clean Solution`
- Right-click MSTest unit testing project
- Added a test case with a deliberate (non-throwing) error that should fail an `Assert` test (the new test case is not run, so no failed test is reported)
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Rebooted computer

So far nothing has resolved the cache issue (existing test cases are run, new test cases are not, breakpoints are not hit in the generator method).

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution?

Comment: @JuanR: Thanks for that suggestion. I have selected `Clean Solution` on the entire solution (containing around 40 projects), and other actions (see update to question). Problem still persists. I suspect there is a physical stale cache file somewhere that needs to be delete, though no idea where to start looking.

Comment: Not a real solution, but you could try using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` inside the generator method.

Comment: @Christian.K: Thanks. Tried adding `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` into the generator method, and breakpoint is not hit!

Comment: If it is caching, then it might be helpful to try to delete all bin and obj directories. Can you give this a try? If this doesn't solve the problem, then I doubt caching is the issue.

Comment: @Jeroen: I was thinking of a caching problem with the Visual Studio `Test Explorer` or `MSTest`. Removing the `bin` and `obj` folders in the unit test project did not help. But in a flash of inspiration, I added a new (dummy) test method with a dummy `DynamicData` generator...and breakpoints and new tests in the original have started working again. Not sure what is going on, but the answer from @Christian.K has a link that shows there are many bugs and issues `MSTest` with `DynamicData`.

Answer (score 0):

The `DynamicaData`-method or property runs during the discovery phase of a test run and values are cached and reused. There are [quite some issues](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues?q=DynamicData) (both open and closed) around `DynamicDataAttribute`. (Personally I already had issues with [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/844).) And things seem to be much more involved internally, than meets the eye.

That is at the time VS invokes the debugger, the method has already been called and a cached value (I *think* `DataContractSerializer` style data somewhere) is used. Deleting the cached data, will not change this behaviour.

To debug such a method, you need to use the following code (as per [this](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/902#issuecomment-876006513)):

```
private static IEnumerable<object[]> SomeGeneratorMethod()
{

    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
    else
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
    }

    // ...
}
```

A simple `Debugger.Break()` is (usually) not enough, because the debugger is simply not active at the discovery phase when you run the test from VS. Which is ultimetly also the reason why a simple breakpoint in the editor will not be hit.

Comment: Danke Christian. That's quite a list of outstanding bugs and issues! Developing these framework is extremely complex, and unforeseen use-cases and bugs are a part of life. I'm assuming the present case is hitting against some limitation in `MSTest` or the Visual Studio `Test Explorer`, because I **appear** to have resolved the issue by defining a new dummy test. Without recourse to your suggestion, breakpoints in the original generator method are now being hit and new test cases are working. Should report this to MS, but unsure how to create a MRE for this issue.